# Correct way to asynchronously load tableview cell data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I try to asynchronously set `UITableViewCell` 'description' field, but due to reusing view cells I have problems when fast scroll my tableview - tableview cells are refreshed several times. My code is below. What's wrong here?

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
    {
        [TimeExecutionTracker startTrackingWithName:@"cellForRowAtIndexPath"];

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MessageCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        CTCoreMessage *message = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UILabel *fromLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        UILabel *subjectLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        UILabel *descriptionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
        [subjectLabel setText:message.subject];
        [fromLabel setText:[message.from toStringSeparatingByComma]];
        [dateLabel setText:[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:message.senderDate
                                                          dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                          timeStyle:nil]];


        NSString *cellHash = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",fromLabel.text,dateLabel.text,subjectLabel.text] md5];

        if([_tableViewDescirptions valueForKey:cellHash] == nil){

            [descriptionLabel setText:@"Loading ..."];

            dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

                BOOL isHTML;
                NSString *shortBody = [message bodyPreferringPlainText:&isHTML];
                shortBody = [shortBody substringToIndex: MIN(100, [shortBody length])];
                [_tableViewDescirptions setValue:shortBody forKey:cellHash];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [descriptionLabel setText:[_tableViewDescirptions valueForKey:cellHash]];

                });
            });
        }else{

            [descriptionLabel setText:[_tableViewDescirptions valueForKey:cellHash]];
        }


        [TimeExecutionTracker stopTrackingAndPrint];

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The block

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [descriptionLabel setText:[_tableViewDescirptions valueForKey:cellHash]];
});
```

*captures* the current value of `descriptionLabel` and will therefore, when the
block is executed, update that label even if the cell has been reused for a different
index path in the meantime.

You should therefore capture the cell instead, and check if the cell's (current) index path is still equal to the original (captured) index path.

You should also update `_tableViewDescirptions` only on the main thread, as it is
used as a *data source*.

This would roughly look like (not compiler tested):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_tableViewDescirptions setValue:shortBody forKey:cellHash];
    if ([[tableView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]) {
        UILabel *descriptionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
        [descriptionLabel setText:[_tableViewDescirptions valueForKey:cellHash]];
    }
});
```

*Side note:* The primary methods to get/set dictionary values are `objectForKey`
and `setObject:forKey:`.
`valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:` are only used for Key-Value coding magic.

Answer (score 2):

I've found an elegant solution, just 3 steps (from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html):

```
 // 1. Create a method for asynch. downloading tableview cell data:

    - (void) loadMessageDescription:(CTCoreMessage *)message forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

            BOOL isHTML;
            NSString *shortBody = [message bodyPreferringPlainText:&isHTML];
            shortBody = [shortBody substringToIndex: MIN(100, [shortBody length])];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                [_messagesDescriptions setValue:shortBody forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",message.hash]];
                [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:104] setText:shortBody];
                //[cell setNeedsLayout];
            });
        });
    }

//2. check for the tableview scrolling when get a tableview cell

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

...

if (_tableView.dragging == NO && _tableView.decelerating == NO){

            [self loadMessageDescription:message forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

...

// 3. When the scroll stopped - load only visible cells

- (void)loadMessageDescriptionForOnscreenRows
{
    NSArray *visiblePaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)
    {
        CTCoreMessage *message = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if([_messagesDescriptions valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",message.hash]] == nil){
            {
                [self loadMessageDescription:message forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate){

        [self loadMessageDescriptionForOnscreenRows];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self loadMessageDescriptionForOnscreenRows];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you only fill your `_tableViewDescirptions` (funny name BTW) dictionary when the async processing is finished and successful. Thus, when the cells race by in a fast scroll, you are setting of lots of async calls again and again.

Instead, always set the description immediately (e.g. with "Loading...") and only do the background task once. Next time this method is called, it will not attempt another download. Of course, you need a fallback if the download fails.

Also I think rather than constructing your expensive string hash, maybe it is possible to use the `indexPath` as the key instead.

Finally, it seems to me that the work you are doing in the background task is trivial and could easily be done in the main thread.

Answer (score -2):

Before You follow my Answer i want to tell you that following code is bad for memory management because it will create new cell for each rows of `UITableView`, so be careful for it.

But it is better to use, When `UITableView` Have Limited rows *(about 50-100 may be )* then following code is helpful in your case. Use it, if it is suitable for you.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

         /// Put your code here.
     }

      /// Put your code here.

    return cell;
}
```

If you have limited rows then this is best code for you.

Comment: Please put comment for @downVote ?? All of this, i mentioned.